# KQOAuth authentification error

Tags: qt, authentication, oauth

I am using KQOauth for the first time and I am having trouble with the following code:

```
 KQOAuthRequest *oauthRequest;
 KQOAuthManager *oauthManager;

 oauthRequest = new KQOAuthRequest;
 oauthManager = new KQOAuthManager(this);
```

The program exits with code 0xc0000135. I have used this example in order to write the code: http://www.gitorious.org/kqoauth/kqoauth/blobs/master/examples/twittercli/twittercli.cpp

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Also, why does new KQOAuthRequest have no brackets?

Comment: 0xC0000135 might indicate a dll problem. How are you launching your program (explorer, QtCreator...), and which dll did you copy in the executable directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the shameless plug, but... after being unsuccessful trying to get KQOAuth to work, I've created my own library, SimpleOAuth.

If you want to try it out, the code is here: https://github.com/gregschlom/SimpleOAuth

And you have my contact info in the readme if you need any help.